# ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a small misunderstanding regards to Artemis console. When I open it on a local host it shows like this:

[image]

However, when I install it on a remote host and open it, it shows like this:

[image: wrong Artemis Console U]

How to make it so that the first variation of UI would show on a remote host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using 2 different versions of ActiveMQ Artemis. The first screenshot is the web console based on Hawtio 1 that was present in version 2.15.0 and earlier. The second screenshot has the web console based on Hawtio 2 that is present in version 2.16.0 which was just released. This work to migrate from Hawtio 1 to 2 was done as part of [ARTEMIS-2838](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2838)